# Create Jmix project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, jmix

I am new to Jmix platform. I have imported the apache license `jmix-all` code into eclipse. But I am not sure how i can create a new project from it. I also know it supports a plugin in IntelliJ but my favorite IDE is what i want. Is there a eclipse plugin as well.

Comment: Nope there is no eclipse plugin :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no support for Eclipse, and there are little chances for it to be added in the future.

The large part of the Jmix (formerly CUBA) ecosystem is the tooling. Jmix team is focusing their efforts to create tooling based on the IntelliJ platform (IntelliJ IDEA).